# A Propositon of Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

- Let $f$ be integrable on $[a, b],$ and suppose $g$ is a function on $[a, b]$ such that

$$g(x)=f(x)$$

except for finitely many $x$ in $[a, b] .$ Show that $g$ is integrable and

$$
\int_{a}^{b} f=\int_{a}^{b} g
$$.

How can I show, can you help?

There is a solution [here](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781461462705-elementary-analysis-the-theory-of-calculus-2nd-edition/280/exercises/7/) (but I couldn't understand, the solution is very complicated.).

Comment: Do you understand that the problem can be reduced to the case when the functions differ at only one point? And further that one point can be taken as $a$ (or $b$). Now the problem is simplified.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is integrable and $f(x) = g(x)$ except at one point $c$.

Since $f$ is integrable, it is bounded by some $B$. For simplicity, assume that
$c$ is in the interior of the interval, the edge cases are similar.

Let $B'=\max(B,|g(c)|)$.

Pick some $\epsilon>0$ and choose points $c_1,c_2$ in the interior of the interval
such that $c_1 < c < c_2$ and $2B'(c_2-c_1) < \epsilon$. Now choose a partition
$P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$, then let $P'$ be the $P$ partition with
the points $c_1,c_2$ added. We note that
$|L(f,P')-L(g,P')| < \epsilon$, $|U(f,P')-U(g,P')| < \epsilon$ and
$U(f,P')-L(f,P') < \epsilon$. Hence we have
\begin{eqnarray}
U(g,P')-L(g,P') & \le &  U(g,P')-U(f,P') + U(f,P')-L(g,P') \\
& < &\epsilon + U(f,P')-L(g,P') \\
& = &\epsilon + U(f,P')-L(f,P')+L(f,P')-L(g,P') \\
& < & 3 \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that $g$ is integrable. Furthermore, since we can always refine a
partition $P$ such that $|L(f,P')-L(g,P')|$ is arbitrarily small, it follows that
$\int g = \sup_P L(g,P) = \sup_P L(f,P) = \int f$.

If $f,g$ differ at a finite number of points we can use the above analysis 
(changing $f$ one point at a time) to show that $\int f = \int g$.

Comment: Why do the Darboux sums over $P$ become equal for $f, g$? Assuming the functions differ only at $a$ then clearly the values $f(a), g(a) $ have a role in determining in the sup and inf of $f, g$ in any interval which contains $a$.

Comment: The sums are not necessarily equal rather $U-L$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing fine partition.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Good catch, sloppy work on my part. I will fix it.

Comment: It happens sometimes. Like in my previous comment I should have written $|U(f, P)-U(g, P) |$ instead of $U-L$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Repaired, I hope.

Comment: I think you can take $A, B$ as bounds for $|f|, |g|$ and $B'=\max(A, B) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Since $g$ only differs from $f$ at $c$ then the formula for $B'$ I used above will give the same value.

Comment: Yes you are right. +1

Answer (score 0):

Because $f-g=0$ a.e., $$  \int (f-g) = 0  \text{.}  $$
Then
$$  \int f = \int (f-0) = \int (f - (f-g)) = \int g  \text{,}  $$
showing $g$ is integrable by showing to what it integrates.

Comment: true but he won't know measure theory yet perhaps